# Handling unique CSV data in distributed load test in Jmeter having test data in only Master

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to implement  distributed load test in Jmeter where i deal with huge csv data files.

After going through number of websites i understood that to use unique test data in each slave machine i should place those unique test data files in each slave machine.

This requires additional amount of efforts.

To overcome that i would like to know if by any chance i can have all the test data files in only Master Machine instead of placing in every slave machine and each user should use unique data?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#HTTP-Simple-Table-Server), you run install it on master machine and access the test data from slaves via [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

The [`READ` endpoint](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) has `KEEP=FALSE` setting so you can remove the data once it's used, this way you will have guarantee that another slave won't reuse the same variable.

You can install HTTP Simple Table Server using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri ,Let me try and get back on your suggestion.